# How can I change Magento theme via query string?

Tags: string, magento, themes

Is it possible to change Magento template via query string?

I am developing a custom template and sometimes I want to check if I broke something, so I want to change via query string the theme for the default one.

I am looing for something like this:

**?_theme=default**

Does something like this exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Programmatically:

You could write an observer that is listening to event `<controller_action_predispatch>`

The observer method could look like this:

```
public function changeTheme(){

   if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('layout_switch') == '1'){
       Mage::getDesign()->setArea(‘frontend’)
                        ->setPackageName(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('package'))
                        ->setTheme(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('theme'));

   }
   return;
}
```

}

Then you would just need to call your page with e.g.

```
yourdomain.com/index.php/layout_switch/1/package/default/theme/default
```

Comment: Hi, this is awesome but I didn't want to code to archive this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no you can't (as far as I know)

However if it's your local installation (which you use only as a development enviroment!) you can use a trick:

[Create another Store view](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fl0BSze0zmA) and assign whatever theme you want to that store view and then access it like `yourstore.com/?___store=storecode`

Answer (score 1):

as simple as 1-2-3.:) Create a new dev theme and copy all the files from the current live theme to the new one (both app/design and sking). Then observe controller_action_predispatch event and then in the observer function simply:

```
$controllerAction = $observer->getControllerAction();
if ($controllerAction->getLayout()->getArea() == Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND) {
$ipAddress = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
$ipAddresses = array('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');

if (in_array($ipAddress, $ipAddresses)) {
Mage::getDesign()->setTheme('theme-wanted');
}
}
```

Very helpful for design tweaks indeed. After the work is finished the observer should be disabled or module deactivated until next time